# Adding winstonjs to non nodejs applications

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

I am looking for logging libraries to log the errors to the external server(i.e., my backend server) and while i search for it i found winston logging library. In the documentation they haven't given any example for how we can use this for non nodejs applications. Can anyone help me on this whether we can use winston logging library for pure javascript applications instead of nodejs to depend on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: SImple: You cant. BTW.: What do you mean with "on nodejs applications" winston is designd/written to work in node.js

Comment: I mean for general web applications which doesn't use nodejs